# ImageSwitcher load images from url

Tags: android, imageswitcher

I'm trying to show images from a URL in a ImageSwitcher. I've tried with:

myImageSwitcher.setImageURI(Uri.parse("http://miurl.com/images/foto01.jpg"));

but it said me this "error":

I/System.out﹕ resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: http://miurl.com/images/foto01.jpg

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solucionated this problem using SliderLayot (https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider), but I'll try to do with ImageSwitcher too.

Answer (score 3):

I know it is late but because I found a better solution for this, would love to share it with all :)

I had to look at the source code of the default `ImageSwitcher` and know how it works. Whenever we use `ImageSwitcher` we set a `ViewFactory` to it. This `ViewFactory` creates `View`s which are then used in the `ImageSwitcher`. Usually we create an `ImageView` in the `ViewFactory`. This `ImageView` is then used in the `ImageSwitcher` class to draw the view with the image source specified. Below is the `setImageResource()` method of the `ImageSwitcher` class.

```
public void setImageResource(@DrawableRes int resid){
    ImageView image = (ImageView)this.getNextView();
    image.setImageResource(resid);
    showNext();
}
```

Let's focus on the first and second line of the method.

```
ImageView image = (ImageView)this.getNextView();
image.setImageResource(resid);
```

`this.getNextView()` gets the view from the `ViewFactory` and casts the view into an `ImageView`. And then, the Drawable resource is set to it.

## Solution

Now, with these information, let's get to the solution! I'm using Volley's `NetworkImageView` , but you can use Picasso or Glide too! You just have to change the code a bit.

We need to create a custom ImageSwitcher. Here's my code

## MyImageSwitcher.java

```
public class MyImageSwitcher extends ImageSwitcher {

    public MyImageSwitcher(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyImageSwitcher(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String url) {
        NetworkImageView image = (NetworkImageView) this.getNextView();
        image.setImageUrl(url, AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader());
        showNext();
    }
}
```

Notice the `setImageUrl()` method. We cast the view we get from `getNextView()` to a `NetworkImageView` and set the Url to it. If you want to use Picasso, then just cast it into an `ImageView` and then use Picasso as it needs to be used.

## Activity

```
MyImageSwitcher imageSwitcher = (MyImageSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.imageSwitcher);
imageSwitcher.setFactory(new ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory() {
        public View makeView() {
            NetworkImageView myView = new NetworkImageView(getApplicationContext());
            myView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            myView.setLayoutParams(new ImageSwitcher.LayoutParams(imageSwitcher.getLayoutParams()));
            return myView;
        }
});
```

If you want to use Picasso, then just use an `ImageView`.

## Layout

```
<xyz.farhanfarooqui.loadingimages.MyImageSwitcher
        android:id="@+id/imageSwitcher"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

## AndroidManifest.xml

Don't forget to include `android.permission.INTERNET` to your AndroidManifest.xml

## Done!

Whenever you want to change the image, do it this way,

```
imageSwitcher.setImageUrl("http://miurl.com/images/foto01.jpg");
```

Comment: where do you get "AppController"??

Comment: @AxelLópez it's the Application file you create if you use Volley, if you're using Picasso or something else you don't need it. Instead of NetworkImageView, just use ImageView and load the image in it.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to achieve the same thing when I landed here. I know it's and old question, but since I don't see an answer, I'll tell you the solution that worked for me.

First of all, I downloaded the image/s that I wanted to show in the imageswitcher  and return them as a Bitmap using this code:

```
InputStream in = new java.net.URL(url).openStream();
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
```

Then I set the bitmap in the imageswitcher using `imageSwitcher.setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap))`.

To use `java.net.URL(url).openStream()`, you'll need to add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">` to your `AndroidManifest.xml`file.

Have in mind that you could change the download code to make it better (checking for timeouts for example), but this is just a basic solutions to start from.

Another thing about what you were using, I think you can't use `setImageURI()` to set an internet resource in your `ImageSwitcher`. Acording to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38654333/setting-image-uri-gives-unable-to-decode-stream-java-io-filenotfoundexception), this method is only for content URIs particular to the Android platform (**Note** that they are talking about an `ImageView` in that post, but I think the same goes to this case).